# Change the opacity of gameobject Unity and Change the look of a sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a unity game, where I have different tiles, (2D) and I was wondering two things.
One, how do you make a sprite more transparent.
And two, how would I change the look of a gameObject. so say we have a dirt block and I want to change it to a stone block. How would do that?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Using code

My errors \/
[image: Errors I recieve]

[image: My Script]
my script ^

[image: The inspector panel]

[image: Errors]

Comment: Do you want to achieve this using code? Or just in the Unity Editor?

Comment: Sorry should have stated that, in Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to do all of this in Code, because you can't change a sprite during runtime inside of the Unity Editor.

To make a Sprite more transparent you have to access the color value of your SpriteRenderer.

```
SpriteRenderer.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
```

This is an example of how it could look. The first three numbers are responsible for the color of the object (R, G, B). The fourth color changes the opacity of your object. This is how it would look with only half the opacity.

```
SpriteRenderer.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.5f);
```

Now to your second question on how to change a texture at runtime.

There are different ways you can go about this.

```
     gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = Resources.Load("img1", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
```

or

```
public Sprite stoneSprite;
SpriteRenderer.sprite = stoneSprite;
```

Comment: Yes that would look good i'll try the first one now, and for the second one where would i substitute my sprites in?

Comment: You have to drag in the sprite you want to change into inside of the inspector. Is this what you meant?

Comment: So I have made the script and put that in there, but a thing doesn't pop up underneath for something to be dragged to.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more or maybe update your answer with some images.

Comment: changed my post

Comment: First you have to create a reference to the sprite renderer: `public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer` and then you drag and drop the SpriteRenderer in the inspector. After you have done this you can call `spriteRenderer.sprite = yourSprite;` EDIT: Do the same with `spriteRenderer.color`

Comment: referenced the sprite renderer, can't see anything to drag.

EDIT:

There is an image of the inspector panel in the question

Comment: There are compile errors in your script that's why you can't drag anything. Do you see any red lines in visual studio that indicate that something is wrong

Comment: attached the visual studios i can't see any red lines or  maybe I'm blind

Comment: Can you update the pictures and post both the error messages and especially the script completely. I need to see the lines in order to help you.

Comment: replace the line when you're trying to change the sprite with this: `spriteRenderer.sprite = dirtSprite;` and replace the line when you change the color with this: `spriteRenderer.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);`

Comment: sorry my computer restarted on me i'm opening unity up nwo

Comment: ok so i replaced the things that you told me to, the errors are now attached all of them.

Comment: You can make it easier for you in the future if you turn on that it shows you where the error is located. https://answers.unity.com/questions/1685250/visual-studio-not-showing-errors-intellisense-not.html Just look at your error messages and it already tells you what is wrong.

Comment: i can't get the visual studio thing to work, i go to external tools and nothing is there

Comment: Do you have a program called Visual Studio Installer. If yes look at the answer by  lodendsg in the link I send you. You have to download the Unity Package

Comment: I can't it is blocked by my administrator, i am on a school laptop

Comment: why are all my sprites pure white now after the color change to have alpha 0.5f?